# Distribution of Java Application

Tags: java, compatibility, game-engine, jython

I am programming a functional Java/Jython game engine and I'd like it to be able to run on most any computer.  Though a computers' Java may be up-to-date it will not recognize "java" as a command (batch).

I'm searching for a solution that results in no extra work for the consumer (downloading/installing JRE) and allows anyone to be able to run the game.

The computer I'm experimenting with 'does' possess JRE 7, however it doesn't recognize 'Java'.

Comment: As noted in the answers: If you include the JRE in your shipped package you can put it in a known directory and set paths and/or invoke it with that knowledge. Otherwise, I don't see a solution short of searching the user's machine for a compatible JRE... which will be painfully slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can ship the JRE with your application and use that JRE for your application. The effect is the same: The application will be started through an executable (wrapper needed) or script (batch) file and the target machine does not need to have a java runtime installed.
Java doesn't have to be 'installed', it just has to be 'present'.
Or You may also:
Use Excelsior JET compiler for that purpose.
See http://www.excelsior-usa.com/ for more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle your game with JRE in your installer.